# Firestore collection group dont working with where clauses

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using **FlutterFire** to develop an Android app using Firebase server-less service.

But, when I try to use collection group to query some data, the query return empty result when I use where clause.

In my database I have one collection called '`users`', Inside every document in '`users`' exist one `subcollection` called '`chats`', like that:

```
users/{userDocument}/chats/{chat}
```

One chat is a conversation between two users, one user has the document chat inside his own document, the other user is referenced by the documentId of document chat, the documentId is stored in uid field using a cloud function onCreated.
[DocumentChat example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzv3S.png)

So, when I try to get all chats using `collectionGroup`, I use:

```
Firestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('chats')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: userId)
        .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true);
```

In this case, 'userId' has the Id of the User 1, and 'uid' has the Id of user 2. In app, userId reference 'uid', and I guarantee the variable userId has the same value of field 'uid'.

I created this code to print userId value

```
static Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStreamChats(userId) {
       print('querying userId: $userId');
       Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream = Firestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('chats')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: userId)
        .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true);
      _stream.listen((_q) => print(_q.documents));
      return _stream;
  }
```

And, when it runs, output this:

I/flutter ( 4044): querying userId: YNANBZqQdNg5wYkzXRTNkPWwCHC3

I/flutter ( 4044): []

When I run this query without the where clause, the query returns all documents inside chats collections.

I don't checked any rules yet, so it's all allowed to **read/write**.

[**Indexes are created**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etGKK.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to show some specific examples of the documents that should match the query.  Since we can't see your data, we don't know if your query actually matches your documents.  We need to be able to see the uid field and userId in your code that matches.

Comment: And what is the exact value of `userId` that you're using in the query?  We can't see what that is.  If it doesn't match the uid, then obviously it won't match.  Try hard coding the value.

Comment: I printed userId in runtime, check now.