# Flutter and Firebase - Get Specific Documents From Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image: This is my database structure part 1][image: database structure part 2]

When you go into posts collection there are documents based on userId. And inside a document there is a new collection named userPosts. Inside userposts you can find postId and the details about the post.

I can get specific user post by using this code

```
postRef = Firestore.instance.collection('posts');

QuerySnapshot snapshot = await postRef
        .document(userId)
        .collection('userPosts')
        .getDocuments();
```

But I want to get all the user posts without naming a specific user. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to query documents among all collections with same name.

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('userPosts')
        .getDocuments();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. but I am getting this error. **The method 'collectionGroup' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'collectionGroup'.**

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I do have a additional question. I got all the documents using your code. but what if I want to filter those documents, example like in the posts there is a attribute called status. I want to get all documents where status is false. I used this code ` QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('userPosts').where("status", isEqualTo: false )
        .getDocuments(); ` . seems like this code is not working ? any idea about this?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately and explain what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524640/firestore-collection-group-dont-working-with-where-clauses) this is the question. seems like you already added some comments to this question. but this question doesn't  have a proper answer.